# How to make a Canvas boundary

Tags: javascript, canvas, switch-statement, boundary

I am trying to make a canvas boundary for my mini-game. I have already created the canvas with a character that can move with the arrows. I used a switch statement to do this, the next step is to create a boundary and I am not sure how to go about that? This is how the Javascript Code looks at the moment:

```
function place(id,x_pos, y_pos)
{
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.style.position = "absolute";
  element.style.left = x_pos + 'px';
  element.style.top = y_pos + 'px';


}

setInterval(update,1);

function update()
{
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
}

function keyPress(e)
{
  let x = e.keyCode;

  let character = document.getElementById("character").getBoundingClientRect();
  let canvasWidth = document.getElementById("canvas").getBoundingClientRect();
  let left = parseInt(character.left,10);
  let top = parseInt(character.top,10)

  switch (x) {

      //left
    case 37:
        place('character', left-15, top);
      break;
      //right
    case 39:
        place('character', left+15, top);
      break;
      //up
    case 38:
        place('character', left, top-15);
      break;
      //down
    case 40:
        place('character', left, top+15);
      break;
  }
  console.log(x)
  return x
}
update()
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason for the update function. You only need to add the event listener once, I don't see what use there is repeatedly adding it. An update function can be useful for game logic, but in this instance it seems superfluous. I'd move "document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);" outside of the update function and for the moment just comment out the interval, function, and call to the function until it is actually needed.

I am not sure if there is a better place to make this suggestion or not, but I figured I should point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the boundary you're talking about is a boundary for your character to move? If so...

You'll want to check in the keyPress method before moving your character.

Something like this:

First, I'd consider renaming `canvasWidth` to something like `canvasBound`, and similarly for your character bounds variable.

```
if (!(characterBound.left - 15 < canvasBound.left)) {
   ...move character left...
} 
... else do nothing (don't have to actually include this)
```

repeat similarly for moving up, down, right, etc. You'll have to play with the values to get it right for your sprite.

Comment: What I mean is, the edges of the canvas are walls that the character can not go passed, because currently the character is going through the walls

Comment: Yep, then what the above is doing should work. It's basically checking if the movement will take the character past the boundaries.

Comment: Yep. Make sure you adjust those numbers! You will likely have to adjust for the width of the sprite.

Comment: I am not using a sprite at the moment, I just create a dot and move that. this is going to be a very simplistic game

Comment: Oh, great. If you want, shoot me a link when it's done, would love to test it out.